# Eigen JacobiSVD cuda compile error

Tags: eigen, nvcc

I've got an error, regarding calling JacobiSVD in my cuda function.

This is the part of the code that causing the error.

```
Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix3d> svd( cov_e, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
```

And this is the error message.

> CUDA_voxel_building.cu(43): error: calling a __host__
>   function("Eigen::JacobiSVD , (int)2> ::JacobiSVD") from a __global__
>   function("kernel") is not allowed

I've used the following command to compile it.

```
nvcc -std=c++11 -D_MWAITXINTRIN_H_INCLUDED -D__STRICT_ANSI__ -ptx CUDA_voxel_building.cu
```

I'm using code 8.0 with eigen3 on ubuntu 16.04.
It seems like other functions such as eigen value decomposition also gives the same error.

Anyone knows a solution? I'm enclosing my code below.

```
//nvcc -ptx CUDA_voxel_building.cu
#include </usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include </usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/SVD>
/*
#include </usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse>

#include </usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense>
#include </usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigenvalues> 

*/





__global__ void kernel(double *p, double *breaks,double *ind,  double *mu, double *cov,  double *e,double *v, int *n, char *isgood,  int minpts, int maxgpu){
    bool debuginfo = false;
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if(debuginfo)printf("Thread %d got pointer\n",idx);
    if( idx < maxgpu){


        int s_ind = breaks[idx];
        int e_ind = breaks[idx+1];
        int diff = e_ind-s_ind;

        if(diff >minpts){
            int cnt = 0;
            Eigen::MatrixXd local_p(3,diff) ;
            for(int k = s_ind;k<e_ind;k++){
                int temp_ind=ind[k];

                //Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, diff> local_p;   
                local_p(1,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3];
                local_p(2,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3+1];
                local_p(3,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3+2];
                cnt++;
            }

            Eigen::Matrix3d centered = local_p.rowwise() - local_p.colwise().mean();
            Eigen::Matrix3d cov_e = (centered.adjoint() * centered) / double(local_p.rows() - 1);

            Eigen::JacobiSVD<Eigen::Matrix3d> svd( cov_e, Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
     /*         Eigen::Matrix3d Cp = svd.matrixU() * svd.singularValues().asDiagonal() * svd.matrixV().transpose();


            mu[idx]=p[ind[s_ind]*3];
            mu[idx+1]=p[ind[s_ind+1]*3];
            mu[idx+2]=p[ind[s_ind+2]*3];

            e[idx]=svd.singularValues()(0);
            e[idx+1]=svd.singularValues()(1);
            e[idx+2]=svd.singularValues()(2);

            n[idx] = diff;
            isgood[idx] = 1;

            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    v[x+ 3*y +idx*9]=svd.matrixV()(x, y);
                    cov[x+ 3*y +idx*9]=cov_e(x, y);
                    //if(debuginfo)printf("%f ",R[x+ 3*y +i*9]);
                    if(debuginfo)printf("%f ",Rm(x, y));
                }
            }
*/

        } else {
            mu[idx]=0;
            mu[idx+1]=0;
            mu[idx+2]=0;

            e[idx]=0;
            e[idx+1]=0;
            e[idx+2]=0;

            n[idx] = 0;
            isgood[idx] = 0;

            for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    v[x+ 3*y +idx*9]=0;
                    cov[x+ 3*y +idx*9]=0;
                }
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: There is no solution. You can't just call random host code from inside kernels. Unless there is a specially written device code library (and I strongly suspect in this case there is not). then what you are attempting to do is impossible.

Comment: Thanks, talonmies. I know that I can't call host code from inside kernels but as far as I know cuda 8.0 support Eigen. And I'm already using Eigen in some of my kernel functions. I think my problem is related only to JacobiSVD and other specific functions in Eigen. Do you still say the problem is just because of calling host function in the kernel?

Comment: Some simple functions and container type from Eigen have been extended to work on the GPU. AFAIK, most of the library has not. As for CUDA 8 "supporting eigen", all that means is that you can compile *host* eigen code with nvcc without it blowing up the CUDA front end, which used to be the case.

Comment: @talonmies This question is very Eigen specific and IMO not really a duplicate of the question you linked to. E.g., I think `Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver` works on cuda (with fixed-sized matrices). And using that makes much more sense here, since the `cov_e` is self-adjoint

Comment: @chtz: OK, it is now an open eigen question. Have at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Ubuntu 16.04 provides Eigen 3.3-beta1, which is not really recommended to be used. I would suggest upgrading to a more recent version. Furthermore, to include Eigen, write (e.g.):

```
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>
```

and compile with `-I /usr/include/eigen3` (if you use the version provided by the OS), or better `-I /path/to/local/eigen-version`.

Then, as talonmies noted, you can't call host-functions from kernels, (I'm not sure at the moment, why `JacobiSVD` is not marked as device function), but in your case it would make much more sense to use `Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver`, anyway. Since the matrix you are decomposing is fixed-size 3x3 you should actually use the optimized `computeDirect` method:

```
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3d> eig; // default constructor
eig.computeDirect(cov_e); // works for 2x2 and 3x3 matrices, does not require loops
```

It seems the `computeDirect` even works on the beta version provided by Ubuntu (I'd still recommend to update).

Some unrelated notes:

1. The following is wrong, since you should start with index 0:

   ```
   local_p(1,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3];
   local_p(2,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3+1];
   local_p(3,cnt) =  p[temp_ind*3+2];
   ```

   Also, you can write this in one line:

   ```
   local_p.col(cnt) = Eigen::Vector3d::Map(p+temp_ind*3);
   ```
2. This line will not fit (unless `diff==3`):

   ```
   Eigen::Matrix3d centered = local_p.rowwise() - local_p.colwise().mean();
   ```

   What you probably mean is (`local_p` is actually *3xn* not *nx3*)

   ```
   Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, Eigen::Dynamic> centered = local_p.colwise() - local_p.rowwise().mean();
   ```

   And when computing `cov_e` you need to `.adjoint()` the second factor, not the first.
3. You can avoid both 'big' matrices `local_p` and `centered`, by directly accumulating `Eigen::Matrix3d sum2` and `Eigen::Vector3d sum` with `sum2 += v*v.adjoint()` and `sum +=v` and computing

   ```
   Eigen::Vector3d mu = sum / diff;
   Eigen::Matrix3d cov_e = (sum2 - mu*mu.adjoint()*diff)/(diff-1);
   ```

Comment: Hi chtz! Thanks for the good tips. Unfortunately, my nvcc became not be able to find gcc after I tried to install different versions of cuda(7.5, 8.0). I will let know if SelfAdjointEigenSolver works once I fix this problem first.

Comment: As you recommended I have installed the latest Eigen and compiled with the option. Fortunately, computeDirect works perfectly in cuda code although JacobiSVD is still marked as a host function. I really appreciate your kind advice on the coding style and proper function to use. It was really helpful for me. Thanks!